# C# Azure AD Graph get all members of a group where are more than 20

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to fetch all users from a specific group from Azure AD. There currently 480 users. When I fetch them I get 20 only I assume this is the default setting?

```
var users = await _gsc.Groups["GROUP_ID"].Request().Expand("members").GetAsync();
```

How can I fetch them all?

EDIT:

Seems if I remove .Expand("members") and use .Members.Request().GetAsync() there is a NextPageResult option on the result ... I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. This is a limitation in the $expand parameter.

If you want all of the groups, retrieve the members attribute and following the oData.NextLink if its present to page through the results.  There are several group related functions described at the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/groups-operations

There are functions that can be used for group transitivity as well, just follow the navigation links generally located on the right of the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Mohit_Garg mentioned that the maximum number of returned objects is 20. For more information, please refer to [Supported queries, filters, and paging options | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#expand).

> The following restrictions apply to $expand expressions:
>
> - The maximum number of returned objects for a request is 20.

---

> Seems if I remove .Expand("members") and use .Members.Request().GetAsync() there is a NextPageResult option on the result ... I'll give it a try.

Yes you are right. we could use the **NextPageRequest** to get all of records. And the number of a page is 100.

The following is demo code.

```
IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage users = _gsc.Groups["GROUP_ID"].Members.Request().GetAsync().Result;
do
{
   
   Console.WriteLine("number:" + users.Count);
   foreach (var usr in users)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("user: {0}", usr.Id);
   }
} 
while(users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result).Count > 0);
```