# How to convert IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage from Azure AD to list/collection in c#?

Tags: c#, list, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to convert an object to a list so i can iterate over the items, how can this be done? The members variable returns a IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage. How can i convert this to a list?

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

```
        try
        {
           // convert members to a list or collection
            var members = await graphClient.Groups["group-id"].Members.Request().GetAsync();

            return new JsonResult(members);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Warning(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To convert **`IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage`** from Azure AD to list, please try the below script mentioned in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804818/list-a-list-of-all-member-from-a-group-using-graph-api) by **user2250152** like below:

```cs
List<User> users = new List<User>();
var groupMembers = await Graph.Groups[groupId].Members.Request().GetAsync();
users.AddRange(groupMembers.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
while(groupMembers.NextPageRequest!=null)
{
    groupMembers = await groupMembers.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    users.AddRange(groupMembers.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
}
```

**Alternatively**, you can try using the below script by **Tony Ju** in this [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376729/how-to-get-list-of-users-belongs-to-a-group-along-with-all-groups-name-he-belong):

```cs
IGroupMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage lstOfAdusers =  graphServiceClient.Groups["groupID"].Members.Request().GetAsync().Result;

var memberoflist=graphServiceClient.Users["userID"].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Please check the below **reference** if it gives you a pointer:

[C# Azure AD Graph get all members of a group where are more than 20 by **Tom Sun - MSFT**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481392/c-sharp-azure-ad-graph-get-all-members-of-a-group-where-are-more-than-20)